# Using the Pardot API with Sandbox Accounts

Tags: api, oauth2, pardot

We've integrated a Pardot Sandbox account with Salesforce using the [Salesforce-Pardot Connector v2](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_setup_v2_setup_main.htm&type=5).

I'm trying to use the Pardot API with an SSO user on a Sandbox Salesforce org (i.e. when creating the Pardot user I enabled 'Enable single sign-on with CRM' as [documented here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_setup_sso.htm&type=5) to convert the Pardot user to an SSO-only user).

I'm obtaining my access token via Salesforce OAuth, as [the documentation](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/authentication/) states:

> To access the Pardot API with an SSO enabled user (including users synced from Salesforce), you must use a Salesforce OAuth endpoint for authentication.

### What I've Tried

I'm making the following request to obtain an OAuth token, which I get successfully. (And yes I'm aware that the OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow should only be used for special scenarios).

```sh
POST https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
client_id={{Connected_App_consumerKey}}
client_secret={{Connected_App_consumerSecret}}
username={{Salesforce_SSO_username}}
password={{Salesforce_SSO_password}}
```

*Note: I assume [the documentation](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/authentication/) is wrong as it states the username is 'the email address of the SSO user account', when I believe they are referring to the username.*

I successfully get back the OAuth token, so far, so good. Next, when I try to use the access token in to create a new batch import in Pardot:

```js
POST https://pi.pardot.com/api/import/version/4/do/create
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Pardot-Business-Unit-Id: 0Uv19000000CaR7CAK

{"operation":"Upsert","object":"Prospect"}
```

I receive the following response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="fail" version="1.0">
    <err code="49">Access Denied</err>
</rsp>
```

I note that this [error code](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/error-codes-messages/#error-code-49) relates to:

> Problem: User is not authorized to perform the requested operation either due to access restrictions or forbidden method of passing credentials

### Additional Info

The SSO user has a 'System Administrator' role and the Selected OAuth Scopes (in the Connected App) include:

- Access and manage your data (api)
- Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
- Access Pardot services (pardot_api)

I've also tried other operations like `/api/prospect/version/4/do/query` and get the same response.

### Possible Cause

My suspicion is that Pardot isn't able to validate the access token as it was issued from a sandbox endpoint (test.salesforce.com instead of login.salesforce.com). But Pardot is integrated with the Sandbox account. Do you know if it's possible to use the Pardot API with a sandbox SSO user? I would assume it would be, but there's no way that I can hint to the Pardot API that this access token was obtained from a sandbox org.

Comment: _But Pardot is integrated with the Sandbox account_ - integrated how? Please edit your post.

Comment: @identigral I've updated the first paragraph to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that Pardot Sandbox accounts use a different API endpoint (this isn't mentioned anywhere in the Pardot API documentation). Instead of using the route:

`https://pi.pardot.com/api/{{objectName}}/version/{{versionNumber}}/do/{{operation}}`

You need to include `demo` in the base URL:

`https://pi.demo.pardot.com/api/{{objectName}}/version/{{versionNumber}}/do/{{operation}}`